# Text Split with Space

Tags: c#, string, split

I have this Line `C:\pagefile.sys 128 256`  and i need to get the value example:

```
label1.text = C:\pagefile.sys
label2.Text = 128;
label3.text = 256;
```

all values are variable, it is possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to specify a whitespace character for `Split` as that's the default if no characters are passed (or if `null` is used). `Split()` is the same as saying `Split(new char[0]);` due to the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) overloaded method.

```
string input = @"C:\pagefile.sys 128 256";
string[] splitString = input.Split();
label1.Text = splitString[0];
label2.Text = splitString[1];
label3.Text = splitString[2];
```

Comment: The next question is probably: I have `C:\Users\Some User Name\foo.txt 128 256` and label1.Text should be `C:\Users\Some User Name\foo.txt` and not `C:\Users\Some`

Comment: I still prefer the explicit space because nobody knows what the default is.

Comment: @dtb I think that's a fair assumption.`Split` wouldn't be the route if the delimiters aren't consistent. @usr - Yes, an explicit whitespace character would be clearer but I thought I'd post the option as well just for added info (at the time, It'sNotALie had posted the alternate method)

Answer (score 5):

```
string[] temp = yourString.Split(' ');
label1.Text = temp[0];
label2.Text = temp[1];
label3.Text = temp[2];
```